# Creating Sliders in Javascript Through Click

Tags: javascript, html, slider

Fairly new to javascript. Currently, I have a few buttons. When a button is clicked a `div` is added to the html that contains a question. Within this question is a slider:

```
<input class="slider" id="Question" type="range" min="0" max="10"</>
<p>value: <span id='display'></span></p>
```

I have then written a javascript function that controls the slider:

```
var slider = document.getElementById('Question');
var output = document.getElementById('display);
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
   output.innerHTML = this.value
};
```

This all works perfectly. The only problem is that if an additionally button is clicked -- now we have two questions & two sliders -- the function can't handle both and the second slider does not have an output. I do have the javascript set up to may the id's of the slider to be unique so that the id becomes `Question-1` rather than just `Question`.

I attempted to alleviate this by placing the sliders into arrays, but the logic there fell apart. Any help being able to add 1 to n sliders and controlling them individually would be helpful.

Comment: maybe this example might help https://jsbin.com/quyayewune/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the code below.

You need to build the HTML but then listen for events.

In the case of the `range` control you want the `change` event.

From there we can use the `scoping` provided buy the `querySelector` method when used against the `parentNode` to ensure we address the correct `span`

```js
// Just dummy to add some questions.
const addNewQuestion = (question) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('question');
  div.innerHTML = `<span>${question}</span>
                   <input type='range' min='0' max='10'>
                   <span class='value'></span>`;
  document.querySelector('.questions').appendChild(div);
}

let currQuestion = 1;

document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('button')) addNewQuestion(`Question ${currQuestion++}`); 
});


// Here is what we need, we listen for a `change` event.
// Then we use querySelector on our parent node to set the correct span.
document.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  if(target.matches('input[type="range"]')) {
    target.parentNode.querySelector('.value').innerHTML = target.value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  
</div>
<button>More Questions</button>
```